# query a JSON type column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, json

I have a table in Postgres and trying to query a `JSON` type columns `data_meta & source_data`

```
request_id               | bbb1-bdfa3ae765a2
job_type                 | Incoming
data_meta                | {"data_type": "Insurance", "technology": "XYZ", "timestamp_column_name": "JOBTIME"}
source_data              | [{"vendor": "ABCD", "name": "MAPPING_FILE", "data_type": "Insurance"}]
status                   | OK


SELECT * FROM   job_request_table p, json_array_elements(p.data_meta) as element
where element->'data_type' ='Insurance';
```

and getting this:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = unknown
LINE 2: where element->'data_type' ='Insurance';
                                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

will there be a change in query if I have to search for `vendor='ABCD'` in another `JSON` type column `"source_data"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extract the value as `text` which is done using the `->>` operator (`->` returns a `json` value).

```
SELECT * 
FROM job_request_table p
  cross join json_array_elements(p.data_meta) as d(element)
where d.element ->> 'data_type' = 'Insurance';
```

However, given your sample data, this would result in the error "*cannot extract elements from an object*" as the content of `data_meta` is not an array.

If you want to test if a JSON value contains a specific key/value pair, use `@>` - but that can only be used with `jsonb`, so you need to cast the column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM job_request_table p
where data_meta::jsonb @> '{"data_type": "Insurance"}';
```

You can use this also to check inside the array in `source_data` (but again a cast to `jsonb` is neeed):

```
where source_data::jsonb @> '[{"vendor": "ABC"}]'
```

---

In the long run, I would recommend to change both columns to `jsonb`

Comment: Thanks. working as expected